# Permission to edit media files (photo captions, alt tags)

Tags: uploads, media, permissions, captions

What permission is required for a user to be able to edit all media files in Wordpress?

I'm trying to edit the captions and alt tags of some media files in Wordpress. I can see the media file in the "Media" section of the WP Dashboard, but if I click on an image then the `Alternative Text`, `Title`, `Caption`, and `Description` fields are all greyed-out; I cannot edit their contents.

I *can* upload media. For any files that I've uploaded, I can edit the above-listed fields. It's just an issue with editing the fields of older photos that were uploaded (by other users) before my account was created.

I see that [there used to be an `edit_files` permission](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/#edit_files) in Wordpress, but the documentation merely says that it's no longer used

> ##### Edit Files
>
> - Since 2.0
> - **Note:** No longer used.
>
> ([source](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/#edit_files))

Unfortunately, I can't find the replacement for the `edit_files` permission.

What granular permission should I ask the WP administrator for that gives me *only* permission to edit all the media files' alt tags, descriptions, and captions -- following the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)?

Comment: See also https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: note that it's possible you've already assigned the capability you need but a precursor is not present. E.g. you can't allow users to modify some parts of a post if they're unable to save the post type to begin with

Comment: You may have to add `edit_posts`, `edit_published_posts`, and/or `edit_others_posts` permission https://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit-the-alt-and-title-of-images-in-the-media-library/